# nodejs update dependencies in package.json from latest to used version

Tags: node.js, npm

I created an app using MEAN stack.

It has a lot of dependencies in package.json app.
Here is an Eg of My package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "myapp",
  "main": "server.js",
  "author": {
    "name": "sayed",
    "email": ""
  },"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "latest",
    "compression": "latest",
    "ejs": "^2.4.2",
    "express": "latest",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.0.0",
    "method-override": "latest",
    "mongodb": "^2.1.20",
    "morgan": "latest",
      "crypto": "latest"
  }
}
```

Now I am deploying my app to a production server & to avoid issues, 
I want to keep the same version in the dependencies from which I developed.

So I need a way to convert "latest" to a specific version from which I developed my app. 
Is there any command to do so ? or I have to manually change the dependencies ?

Answer (score 0):

When I deleted my `node_modules` dir

```
npm update --save
```

worked for me updating dependencies versions in `package.json`

Comment: After deleting node_modules, It only changed those packages which were local. & it added a "^" i.e. a minimum version. I am looking for a specific version.